# ownclod update to 10.5

Tags: apt, repository, owncloud-server

I have installed owncloud 10.4 with the owncloud repository.

When I do a

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

I get a message with release upgrade has to be accepted.

```
N: Repository 'https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/production/Ubuntu_18.04  Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'obs://s2.owncloud.com/ce:10.3/Ubuntu_18.04' to 'obs://s2.owncloud.com/ce:10.5/Ubuntu_18.04'
N: Repository 'https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/production/Ubuntu_18.04  Release' changed its 'Label' value from 'ce:10.3' to 'ce:10.5'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this do

```
sudo apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update
sudo apt update
sudo aot upgrade
```

This will accept the new release and download the new files.